Failed to install TensorRT-LLM by poetry add
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1
Poetry version: 1.8.4
I want to install TensorRT-LLM by poetry, the command is

poetry add tensorrt-llm

But it raises errors:
Using version ^0.14.0 for tensorrt-llm

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (5.9s)

Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

Installing pywin32 (308): Failed
RuntimeError
Unable to find installation candidates for pywin32 (308)

at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:74 in choose_for
70│
71│ links.append(link)
72│
73│ if not links:
→ 74│ raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
75│
76│ # Get the best link
77│ chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
78│

Cannot install pywin32.

But pywin32 is for windows, I don't know why poetry would install pywin32 in Ubuntu.
I tried the command with specific platform

poetry add tensorrt-llm --platform linux

But it still raises the same errors, how should I install TensorRT-LLM with poetry? Thanks

tensorrt-llm has an unconditional requirement on pywin32 - see https://inspector.pypi.io/project/tensorrt-llm/0.14.0/packages/1f/93/384befbf1b7a1d7e09eef4829e0dfb2dcf07a1b7f21cdfa368dc01605be0/tensorrt_llm-0.14.0.tar.gz/PKG-INFO#line.28
you should report a bug to that project
